# Gradle Build connection timeout after Cloning from git

Tags: android, gradle, build, connection, reset

I am trying to clone a project from git.
After the VCS import via the link from git, the gradle build starts downloading a bunch of files. 
After ~30 minutes (!) the error "connection reset" pops up, cancelling gradle and leaving me unable to view previews for xmls I am trying to edit (I am part of a 4-man Uni-project-team and this is my task).

Please note that I am all new to Android Programming and have 0 experience at all, this is my first project.

As I have no experience so far, the only thing I've tried is removing the gradle folder and then trying again, hopefully to replace the (maybe?) corrupted files. 
Also I have tried to clone again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For android studio try go on importing downloaded file of github.
For that go in File -> new -> Import Project..
then select folder.

Comment: I did import the project this way, and wow, no gradle build loop anymore. Thanks!
Now I have to sync the local project to the git project - if someone is eager to help me on this, I'd be very happy.